# enabling anonymous users to SharePoint 2013

Tags: anonymous-authentication

I am trying to enable anonymous users to access the site or maybe some pages on the site and I have made the regular steps, but still it is not working.

I have enabled anonymous on the web application.

Site settings -> Permission settings -> Anonymous Access -> Entire web site and also I've stopped the inheritance for the site

After that it's still not working on the server but it works with me on LocalHost but not work with me on the server!.

any help please?

What else do I need to do?